# Nginx redirection (subdomain to url)

Tags: nginx

I bought a site using this format for user account URLs: `username.purchasedsite.com`.

I pointed `purchasedsite.com` to my new server after importing the data from the old site to my own application which uses this URL format `mydomain.com/app/username`

Now how can I redirect all visits to `username.purchasedsite.com` to `mydomain.com/app/username`?

I tried this and the user it redirected to http://mydomain.com/app/ without the subdomain!

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name purchaseddomain.com ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.purchaseddomain.com;

        rewrite (.*)$ http://mydomain.com/app/$subdomain;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
server {
     listen  80;
     server_name  ~ ^(?<username>\w+)\.purchasedsite\.com$;
     rewrite ^ http://mydomain.com/app/$username$request_uri? permanent; 
}
```

Comment: There are thousands of subdomains. I can't hardcode it like this.

Comment: I have change my answer. I tested it. 
P.S. There was no word of the thousands subdomains in the first variant of your question.

Comment: Needed to change ~ ^ to ~^ but otherwise worked great!